# Search subString in String which starts and ends with special character - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to search and replace substring in string which starts and ends with special character.

```
string myString = "FIELD COMPARRISON SAME ROWîSTLîTHEATRE_CASEîCLIENT_IDî==î*EMERGENCY_CLINICAL_PRIORITY_LOCAL_CODE*í";
```

** I want to replace *EMERGENCY_CLINICAL_PRIORITY_LOCAL_CODE* with some other value **

Edit:  Sorry my fault.

I want to replace EMERGENCY_CLINICAL_PRIORITY_LOCAL_CODE with some other value.

currently am using IndexOf to find first and second instance of * and then get the string with above indexes.  How this can be achieved in RegEx?

Comment: Why would you want to use RegEx when native string methods are faster, more efficient? Why is `IndexOf` not good enough?

Comment: Yes, it works fine.  I want acheive this in RegEx and I know there is way to do this in RegEx.  I think we can use RegEx.Matches(string, pattern), just cannot figure it out the pattern to use.

Comment: In this case, I would say Regex == overkill...I agree with kzen, string methods should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char  marker = 'í';
Regex regex = new Regex (string.Format ("(?<={0})([^{0}]*)", marker));
regex.Replace (input, "replacement");
```

By the way, if marker ever changes, you may need to use `Regex.Escape(marker)` instead of `marker` in the string.Format.